# ng-table reset page to 1 on sort

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I am using ng-table in my application, I was looking to reset current page to 1 when user changes sort order. I gone through ng-table [documentation](http://ng-table.com/#/sorting/demo-api), but no use.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this via the `page()` function of `NgTableParams`:

```
$scope.tableParams.page(1);
```

For that, you need to subscribe to the `ngTableEventsChannel.afterReloadData();` that is fired after sorting changes. There's an [example](http://ng-table.com/#/events/demo-subscribe) that logs the events and shows how to subscribe.

Comment: Its after reload of data, I am looking for after sort changes. If the page changes, it fires afterReloadData events, and it will again set to first page.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
    var vm = this;
    vm.tableParams = new NgTableParams();
    vm.recentPage = 1;

    ngTableEventsChannel.onAfterDataSorted(function() {
        vm.tableParams.page(1);
        vm.tableParams.reload();
    }, $scope, function(tableParams) {
        var reset = tableParams._params.page !== 1 && vm.recentPage === tableParams._params.page;
        vm.recentPage = tableParams._params.page;
        return reset;
    });
```